# Tomcat 9.0.8 Http status 404

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I installed tomcat 9.0.8 . I switched location to localhost.server and I changed server location to use tomcat installation but i still i cannot open homepage of tomcat.i get http status 404 error. When i see in console after starting the web server i get the below error. i also get pushing tomcat v9.0.8 server at localhost encountered a problem.

```
SEVERE: Unable to create directory for deployment: [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\conf\Catalina\localhost]
May 30, 2018 9:29:21 PM org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve open
SEVERE: Failed to open access log file [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\logs\localhost_access_log.2018-05-30.txt]
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\logs\localhost_access_log.2018-05-30.txt (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.open(AccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.startInternal(AccessLogValve.java:685)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:179)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:963)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)

May 30, 2018 9:29:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\docs]
May 30, 2018 9:29:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext postWorkDirectory
WARNING: Failed to create work directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\work\Catalina\localhost\docs] for context [/docs]
May 30, 2018 9:29:28 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
May 30, 2018 9:29:28 PM org.apache.jasper.EmbeddedServletOptions <init>
SEVERE: The scratchDir you specified: [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\work\Catalina\localhost\docs] is unusable.
May 30, 2018 9:29:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\docs] has finished in [6,463] ms
May 30, 2018 9:29:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\manager]
May 30, 2018 9:29:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext postWorkDirectory
WARNING: Failed to create work directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\work\Catalina\localhost\manager] for context [/manager]
May 30, 2018 9:29:33 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
May 30, 2018 9:29:33 PM org.apache.jasper.EmbeddedServletOptions <init>
SEVERE: The scratchDir you specified: [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\work\Catalina\localhost\manager] is unusable.
May 30, 2018 9:29:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\manager] has finished in [5,186] ms
May 30, 2018 9:29:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\ROOT]
May 30, 2018 9:29:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext postWorkDirectory
WARNING: Failed to create work directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\work\Catalina\localhost\ROOT] for context []
```

Comment: `Access denied` permissions problem shown in this line `
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\logs\localhost_access_log.2018-05-30.txt (Access is denied)`. The user running tomcat does not have write permissions on that directory.

Comment: how to get write permission? @LuisMuñoz

Comment: That's OS related, search how to do that for your OS.

Comment: Thank you @LuisMuñoz it worked

Comment: where did you learn that? @LuisMuñoz

Comment: It's a basic Multiuser OS issue. When several users work together the OS defines levels of access. Windows, Linux, MacOS do that.

Answer (score 0):

The error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\logs\localhost_access_log.2018-05-30.txt (Access is denied)
```

clearly shows that it is an access issue, most likely that you don't have the permission for access(most likely the writing permission) the file.

Since you are using a windows OS, if you are not the administrator, probably you have to contact your administrator to open that right for you.